# Erro ao tentar iniciar o emulador do android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, emulador

Estou começando a estudar react native, mas sempre que eu tento iniciar o emulador da um erro.

```
C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Documents\Junior\Android\curso-react-native\exercicios>emulat
or -list-avds
Nexus_5X_API_25<br>
Nexus_5X_API_27

C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Documents\Junior\Android\curso-react-native\exercicios>emulat
or -no-snapshot -avd Nexus_5X_API_25

[204]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found
at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch 'C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Documents\Junior\Android\curso-react-native
\exercicios\..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-armel.exe': No such file
 or directory
```

Primeiro tentei no meu celular mas só fica em uma tela vermelha quando dou o comando `react-native run-app`.
Ai então eu resolvi tentar pelo emulador, mas não consigo inicia-lo dessa forma.
 Então eu tentei dessa forma:

```
C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Documents\Junior\Android\curso-react-native\exercicios>C:\Use
 rs\MIDIASILK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd
 Nexus_5X_API_25
```

Mas aí da um crash chamado:

```
Android emulator closed unexpectedly.
```

Logo então tentei rodar pelo expo com um cabo usb, mas sempre que rodo `react-native run-android` meu celular fica com uma tela vermelha de erro.

Alguém saberia dizer porque isso fica acontecendo? Eu conseguindo rodar o expo ou o outro método estaria perfeito.

Só lembrando que minha maquina tem instalado já o node, jdk, as variaveis de ambiente do jdk e do android studio já estão definidas, o python tbm tá instalado e instalei os pacotes necessários para rodar o react native.

Comment: O que está acontecendo é q o ambiente não está configurado corretamente. O próprio erro indica isso **[204]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found
at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib**. É muito importante ler o erro que acontece.

Comment: Esquecendo um pouco a execução por linha de comando, você consegue iniciar o emulador normalmente pelo Android Studio?

Comment: Perdão a demora para responder. Eu também não consigo executar pelo android studio, simplesmente não abre.

Answer (score 0):

Célio, sobre o device físico, para rodar com o expo basta ter no seu celular o expo instalado. 
E no computador o expo cli. 
A melhor forma de rodar com o expo é utilizando o yarn (substituto do npm), para instalar : `npm install -g yarn.`

Em seguida, yarn start (para inicipar um projeto feito com expo). 
Ele irá abrir uma aba no seu navegador com um QRCode e você irá ler o QRCode pelo expo no seu celular, ai o projeto irá rodar.

Para rodar sem o expo, o seu celular deve estar na mesma rede que o computador, e todas as bibliotecas necessárias instaladas no pc (android sdk, java, adb etc).

Para verificar se o seu device está conectado corretamente:

```
adb devices
```

caso ocorra erro é sempre bom digitar

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Esses comandos  reiniciam o servidor ADB, que é o responsável pela comunicação entre máquina e celular.

O seu emulador pode estar com diversos problemas, desde falta de libs até problema na virtualização...